# Error consuming WCF service form UWP app (Raspberry PI 3)

Tags: c#, wcf, uwp

I built a simple IoT UWP app containing 1 button and 1 text field.
Pushing the button shall call a function from the WCF service and display the result inside the text field.

- I designed my app
- In the same VS project I created a new WCF application with the default functions inside
- I added the WCF application as a service reference.
- After compiling the UWP app I runs without issues.
- As soon as I push the button, I get the following error messages:

  `Exception thrown: 'System.Exception' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
  Exception thrown: 'System.Exception' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
  Exception thrown: 'System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException' in System.Private.ServiceModel.dll
  Exception thrown: 'System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
  Exception thrown: 'System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
  Exception thrown: 'System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException' in System.Net.Http.dll
  Exception thrown: 'System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
  Exception thrown: 'System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException' in System.Private.ServiceModel.dll
  Exception thrown: 'System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
  Exception thrown: 'System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
  Exception thrown: 'System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException' in System.Private.ServiceModel.dll
  Exception thrown: 'System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
  An exception of type 'System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException' occurred in System.Private.CoreLib.dll but was not handled in user code
  Additional information: net_http_client_execution_error`

The event handler for the button in my UWP looks as follows:

```
private async void  button_GetData_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {            
            Service1Client cl = new Service1Client();
            await cl.OpenAsync();
            var res = await cl.GetDataAsync(12);
            txtData.Text += res;
    }
```

My service looks as follows:

```
using System;
namespace WCF_Temp
    {
    public class Service1 : IService1
    {
        public string GetData(int value)
        {
        return string.Format("You entered: {0}", value);
        }
    }
```

I ran out of ideas... Is anyone having the same trouble?

Thanks in advance!
    }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code was simple in your WCF, and your client code also was simple. So, it's hard to locate your issue if just checking your code snippet.

You might need to do troubleshooting. For example,

1. You could add some break points in your WCF and client code to debug.
2. You could input your WCF service address in your favorite browser to test if your service work. If it worked well in browser, you might need to check if you have add reference to your WCF services correctlly in your UWP client.
3. You could use [fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler) to capture traffic and check if the request has been sent successfully.

In addition, if you don't know how to debug WCF service, please check this document [Debugging WCF Services](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb514135.aspx)

Comment: Hi, regarding your advices:
1. the error seems to appear in line `var res = await cl.GetDataAsync(12);`

2. In the browser it is displayed correctly.


3. How can I capture traffic with fiddler which is installed on my local machine , whereas the communication happens between WCF on my remote machine and UWP app also on my remote machine?

Comment: @bluefox Please check [Capture Traffic from Another Machine (Any OS)](http://docs.telerik.com/fiddler/Configure-Fiddler/Tasks/MonitorRemoteMachine) and [Configure Fiddler for UWP applications](http://docs.telerik.com/fiddler/Configure-Fiddler/Tasks/ConfigureFiddlerForWin8). Besides, please check for loop back issues and get the exact error message. See document https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn640582.aspx for more details.

Comment: THanks for your reply. Finally, I solved it by updating to Built  16299 which supports functions out of .NET core 2.0 that I outsourced to the WCF. as of now I don't need the WCF anymore and can place all needed features directly inside my UWP app.